# Mysql fetch unicode text (hindi) to record set/file php codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, csv, unicode

```
Problem: Not getting unicode (hindi) text in mysql record set/php array
```

**I am using mysql database and i have below value in column MyText of table unicode :**

```
इस परीक्षण के प्रयोजन के लिए हिन्दी पाठ इस प्रकार है|
```

**Now if i run query in php myadmin : Select Mytext from unicode**

I will get result as 
इस परीक्षण के प्रयोजन
के लिए हिन्दी पाठ इस
प्रकार है|

**But if i run same query using php (or codeigniter) i am getting below result:**

à¤¸à¤µà¤¾à¤°à¥€ à¤¤à¤• à¤ªà¤¹à¥à¤‚à¤
šà¤¨à¥‡ à¤•à¥‡ à¤®à¤¿à¤¨à¤Ÿ

```
My database setting in codeigniter:
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'MYDATABASENAME';    
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

What i have tried before query:

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8') or die(mysql_error());
              mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8') or die(mysql_error());
              mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8') or die(mysql_error());
              mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8') or die(mysql_error());
              mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8') or die(mysql_error());
              mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8') or die(mysql_error());
            mysql_query("set names 'utf8'") or die(mysql_error());
            mysql_query('SET collation_connection=utf8_general_ci') or die(mysql_error());

             mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'"); 
             mysql_query ("set character_set_client='utf8'"); 

         mysql_query ("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
         mysql_query ("SET CHARACTER SET");
```

Comment: Run "show session variables;" in phpmyadmin to see its effective config. And do not use mysql_* functions, they are deprecated, use mysqli* or pdo instead.

Comment: I have tried.. also mysqli but not working..

Answer (score 0):

A string like `à¤¸à¤µà¤¾à¤°` is the result of encoding an UTF-8 string as UTF-8, and then decoding it with an 8-bit code page. You can recognise that by recurring character patterns every 2 or 3 characters (`à¤` in your case).

So probably you're getting the correct string from the database, encoded as  UTF-8, but you're doing something wrong when processing it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You have Mojibake.

- The bytes you have in the client are correctly encoded in utf8 (good).
- You connected with `SET NAMES latin1` (or `set_charset('latin1')` or ...), probably by default.  (It should have been `utf8`.)
- The column in the tables may or may not have been `CHARACTER SET utf8`, but it should have been that.